# Zigzag Conversion - function gets called infinitely

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm on the "Zigzag conversion" problem on Leetcode (https://leetcode.com/problems/zigzag-conversion/description/), and I noticed something weird.

I basically have a "startIndex" that tracks the start of each row, then proceeds to fill the rest of the row by alternating between two "jumps." In the case of a string with 13 letters and rowNum = 4, for example, startIndexes are 0, 1, 2, 3 and the first row will have jumps of 0 and 6, and the second row has jumps of 2 and 4, and so forth.

What I find strange is that my function runs multiple times until it times out - by that, I don't mean the while loop never finishes. If I put a console.log at the very beginning of the solution, that keeps logging until I see the time limit error. Since other solutions are running fine, I'm inclined to think that it's an error on my part. Can anyone figure out what's wrong?

```
var convert = function(s, numRows) {
    var startIndex = 0;
    var result = "";
    while (startIndex <= numRows-1) {
        const jump1 = (numRows-1-startIndex)*2;
        const jump2 = startIndex*2;
        var currIndex = startIndex;

        if (!jump1) {
            while (currIndex < s.length) {
                result += s[currIndex];
                currIndex += jump2;
            }
        }
        
        else if (!jump2) {
            while (currIndex < s.length) {
                result += s[currIndex];
                currIndex += jump1;
            }
        }

        else {
            var isJump1 = true;
            while (currIndex < s.length) {
                result += s[currIndex];
                currIndex += isJump1 ? jump1 : jump2;
                isJump1 = !isJump1;
            }
        }
        startIndex++;
    };
    return result;
};
```

[image]

Comment: Your code does work (ie it produces the expected output from the examples, but I didn't do an extensive testing). But those sites oftentimes have very strict time-limits, that prevents submitting the simple straight forward solution. So probably, while your code in principle does what it's supposed to do, it may simply not be efficient enough to meet those timelimits.

Comment: Hi @derpirscher, it is weird though because if I console.log the start of the solution, it runs 3 times. Please see the screenshot I attached.

Comment: They probably execute at least three testcases. And the third one seems to fail ...

Comment: Furthermore, as a general hint: Some of those competitive websites base their test on the stdout of your proposed solution. Ie, they require a very specific output and will fail if that output isn't met exactly. So adding addional test output may lead to failing tests. (It doesn't seem to be the case for this particular site, though)